# Selenium Actions DragAndDrop does not work between two ag-grid

Tags: c#, selenium

Selenium `_actions.DragAndDrop(source, target).Perform();` does not work between two ag-grid. There is no error but drag and drop is not performed. Here is a [sample](https://www.ag-grid.com/example-runner/angular.php?section=javascript-grid-drag-and-drop&example=two-grids&multi=1&grid=%7B%22noStyle%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22100%25%22%2C%22enterprise%22%3Anull%7D) provided by ag-grid for testing.

I also tried using this javascript [solution](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/26500/22575) but it is not working either, I keep getting following error: `e.dataTransfer.setDragImage is not a function`.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59205188/drag-and-drop-not-working-using-actions-when-draggable-true-using-selenium-and-c/59211287#59211287) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44153189/drag-and-drop-not-working-in-selenium-code/44153962#44153962) discussion answers your question?

Comment: It doesn't help. The sample I provided complies with html5 requirement, but selenium actions do not work on it.