# How to perform drag and drop on HTML5 element using Selenium 3.141.59 + Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriverwait

I am unable to perform drag and drop on HTML5 element using Selenium 3.141.59 + java (1.8). I have tried other solutions(through JavaScriptExecutor) as well which are mentioned in this group. But no solutions are working. Could you please help me to provide a concrete solution for my issue.

I am using Selenium(3.141.59) + Java (1.8) + Cucumber Framework + Selenium Grid (4)

I have followed the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144948/how-to-perform-drag-and-drop-using-selenium-and-python) but it is for python but I need a solution in Java.

Comment: As per the comment on your other question, "update the question with the text based relevant HTML and your code trials", in other words what you have tried so far and the results in each case. Otherwise your question is at risk of being closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with selenium 4. And I found this javascript works for me. I cannot find the link of the discussion but the code snippet below:

```
WebElement From = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Source_locator));
WebElement To = driver.findElement(By.xpath(Target_locator));;
    
    //HTML 5
            final String java_script =
                    "var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
                            "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun" +
                            "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(for" +
                            "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea" +
                            "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev" +
                            "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);" +
                            "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('" +
                            "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit(" +
                            "'drop',tgt);emit('dragend',src);";
    
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(java_script, From, To);
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform [*dragAndDrop()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153962/7429447) as an example within the [website](http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*elementToBeClickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63301869/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/scripts/drag-drop-custom/demo-drag-drop-3.html")
  WebElement  drag = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='Rome']")));
  WebElement  drop = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'box') and text()='South Korea']")));
  new Actions(driver).dragAndDrop(drag, drop).build().perform();
  ```

Comment: i tried to implement the same as you have mentioned,   but it is not working. Are you sure will it work for HTML5 non native / semantic element?

Comment: @SatyabrataDas There was a typo, corrected it now. Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: yes i knew the typo , so i corrected it by myself and tested as well. But it is not working