# Selenium Drag and Drop not working for Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, webdriver, selenium-java

I need to perform a Drag and Drop using Selenium and Java. I used dragAndDrop() method in Action class for this. but it didn't work. From element is selected but its not moving to the To element. I checked the Xpath of the To element. No problem with the Xpath.

This is the screen that I try to automate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM4BL.png)

These are the codes that I tried

```
    public void dragAndDropUsers(String username) throws InterruptedException {
        //Actions class method to drag and drop
        Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        WebElement from = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+username+"')]"));
        WebElement to = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Sequential Approval Order']/following-sibling::p-tree"));

        builder.dragAndDrop(from,to).build().perform();

    }
```

above code selecting the To element. But not move.

```
    public void dragAndDropUsers(String username) throws InterruptedException {
        //Actions class method to drag and drop
        Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement from = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+username+"')]"));
        WebElement to = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Sequential Approval Order']/following-sibling::p-tree"));

        builder.clickAndHold(from).moveToElement(to).release().perform();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }
```

same result for above code. (selecting the To element. But not move. )

```
public void dragAndDropUsers(String username) throws InterruptedException {
        //Actions class method to drag and drop
        Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        
        WebElement from = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+username+"')]"));
        WebElement to = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Sequential Approval Order']/following-sibling::p-tree"));

        JavascriptExecutor _js = (JavascriptExecutor) WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver();
        _js.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).simulate('drag-n-drop',{dragTarget:arguments[1],interpolation:{stepWidth:100,stepDelay:50}});", from, to);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

    }
```

Above code displayed an error as "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: $(...).simulate is not a function"

```
public void dragAndDropUsers(String username) throws InterruptedException {
        //Actions class method to drag and drop
        Actions builder = new Actions(WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver());
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement from = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+username+"')]"));
        WebElement to = WebDriverHelper.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Sequential Approval Order']/following-sibling::p-tree"));
        int x = to.getLocation().getX();
        int y = to.getLocation().getY();

        System.out.println("x coordinate: "+x);
        System.out.println("y coordinate: "+y);

       builder.moveToElement(from)
               .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .clickAndHold(from)
               .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .moveByOffset(x, y)
               .moveToElement(to)
               .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
               .release().build().perform();

       Thread.sleep(5000);

    }
```

Above code is also selecting the From element. But not moving.

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not that super clear in which website you attempted the [*dragAndDrop*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44153962/7429447) functionality.

However as a demonstration within the website [Droppable | jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) you can simulate [*dragAndDrop*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59211287/7429447) functionality as follows:

- Code block:

  ```
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
  driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.demo-frame")));

  //Identify the draggable element
  WebElement dragMe = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Drag me to my target']")));

  // Identify droppable area
  WebElement dropHere = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//p[text()='Drop here']")));
  Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
  actions.dragAndDrop(dragMe, dropHere).build().perform();
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: dragAndDrop]

Comment: Thank you undetected Selenium. I tried this code block. But it didn't works for me.  After executing this "dragMe" element is selected but its not moved and dropped to the "dropHere" element. That is the issue I had previously.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3604

[Why drag and drop is not working in Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436870/why-drag-and-drop-is-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver)

You can try workarounds suggested.

You can try below code. Here I have moved the element to 0,0 co-ordinate and then moved it to final destination place :

```
    Rectangle fromRec = fromEle.getRect();
    Rectangle toRec = toEle.getRect();
    int sX = fromRec.getX() + fromRec.width / 2;
    int sY = fromRec.getY() + fromRec.height / 2;
    int eX = toRec.getX() + toRec.getWidth() / 2;
    int eY = sY;

    PointerInput input = new PointerInput(Kind.MOUSE, "default mouse");
    Sequence seq = new Sequence(input, 0);
    seq.addAction(
        input.createPointerMove(Duration.ofSeconds(2), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), sX, sY));
    seq.addAction(input.createPointerDown(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));
    seq.addAction(
        input.createPointerMove(Duration.ofSeconds(2), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), eX, eY));
    seq.addAction(input.createPointerMove(Duration.ofSeconds(2), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), 0, 0));
    seq.addAction(
        input.createPointerMove(Duration.ofSeconds(2), PointerInput.Origin.viewport(), eX, eY));
    seq.addAction(input.createPointerUp(PointerInput.MouseButton.LEFT.asArg()));

    ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).perform(Collections.singletonList(seq));
```

Comment: Thank you Reyan. I tried these suggested workarounds. But these things didn't work in my case. Some code blocks selecting the draggable element but not moving it to Element that needs to be dropped.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Check if this works.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void dragAndDropUsers(String username) throws InterruptedException {
    //Actions class method to drag and drop
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    WebElement from = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+username+"')]"));
    WebElement to = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Sequential Approval Order']/following-sibling::p-tree"));

    builder.dragAndDrop(from,to).perform();

} 


try this i will work 
In action class you need to pass webdriver object reference variable
```